# Changing words within a text file c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ program that changes all the iterations of a certain words in a text file. I have my code written below.

However, it does do it unless there are other characters surrounding the string. For example the word "chair" is changed to "table" unless in the text file, the word "chair" has a full stop after it. For example, in the text "He sat on the chair.", the word "chair" would not be replaced. The part of the code that does the replacement is

```
if (s == argv[2]) {
      cout << argv[3];
}
else {
      cout << s; }
```

Where `argv[2]` is the word you are finding, `argv[3]` is the word that you want to replace it with and `s` is the new string that I am creating. This is within a while loop.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't post all of the _relevant_ code I'm guessing you'll be better off using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), and [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Comment: When you compare strings, you should use `strcmp()`

Comment: At a guess, your problem is that when you read a word from the file, if it has punctuation (not just '.' --'!' and '?' will also frequently arise) immediately following the letters, that will be read in as part of the word so when you do your comparison it doesn't match (i.e., `"chair" != "chair.").

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem lies on how you read the text. You might have read the text until the next space into `s` and directly comparing the whole string to the word to be searched. This logic is definitely flawed. You need to do a search on the input token.

Comment: Jerry that is exactly my problem

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a possible solution.

```
string s;   //This contains the contents of the file
string punctuation = ".!?:;, ";
string wordtofind = "chair";
string wordtochangeinto = "table";


for(int pos = -1;(pos = s.find(wordtofind, pos + 1)) != string::npos;)
{//Found an occurence of "chair"
    if(((pos != 0) 
             && (s.substr(pos - 1, 1).find_first_of(punctuation) == string::npos)) 
       || ((pos != s.lenght() - 1) 
             && (s.substr(pos + wordtofind.lenght(), 1).find_first_of(punctuation) == string::npos)))
    {//There was no punctuation mark on both sides, so we skip this find
        continue;
    }

    s.replace(pos, wordtofind.length() , wordtochangeinto); //Replace "chair" with "table"
}

cout << s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little amount of code you provided and the follow-up comments it's clear there are at least a couple of problems with your approach. The first problem is dealing with the punctuation surrounding each word and the second problem is maintaining line endings. Both of these problems are directly related to reading in a single word at a time (i.e. `std::cin >> stringVar`). These problems can be resolved by reading in an entire line and then doing a simple search and replace on the input line.

You will most certainly want to check the characters before and after the search criteria in order to determine if it's part of a word or surrounded by certain punctuation. Depending on what your requirements are this might be as simple as using calls like `std::isalpha` or `std::isalnum` available in the C++ Standard Library. Alternatively you can also provide custom search criteria as shown in Vincent's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26678323/845568) but that depends on your requirements.

The code below demonstrates how to do this with comments describing key parts. It uses `std::istringstream` for the input stream and a hard coded needle and replacement string but should help you get to where you need to go.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    //  `input` represents the input stream which could be your file.
    std::istringstream input(
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
        "The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
        "The xquick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
        "The quickx, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
        "The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
        "The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, quick\n"
        "The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, quickly\n"
        );

    //  The following can be changed to needle(argv[2]) and newWord(argv[3])
    //  to search and replace based on strings provided on the command line
    const std::string needle("quick");
    const std::string newWord("slow");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
        for (
            auto pos = line.find(needle, 0);
            pos != std::string::npos;
            pos = line.find(needle, pos))
        {
            //  Get the character before the found string or space if at
            //  beginning of line.
            const char leftChar = pos > 0
                ? line[pos - 1]
                : ' ';

            //  Get the character after the found string or space if at the end
            //  of the line.
            const char rightChar = pos + needle.size() < line.size()
                ? line[pos + needle.size()]
                : ' ';

            //  Check to see is the characters before and after meet the criteria
            //  necessary to replace the string. We need to do this in order to
            //  prevent replacing substrings of a word (i.e. `it` in `smitten`.
            //  Replace std::isalpha with std::isalnum or your own function that
            //  tests for characters that do not appear in words.
            if (!std::isalpha(leftChar) && !std::isalpha(rightChar))
            {
                line.replace(pos, needle.size(), newWord);
                pos += newWord.size();
            }
            else
            {
                pos += needle.size();
            }
        }
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output

> The slow brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The slow, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The xquick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The quickx, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The slow, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The slow, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, slow
>   The slow, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, quickly

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> if (s == argv[2])
> ```

Yikes! Please use strcmp or some equivalent of it? You're comparing pointers otherwise.

When reading out the string from the file, are you ensuring that 'chair' is read instead of 'chair.'?

putline/puts is your friend here during writing things to the file.

Comment: At least assuming `S` is of type `std::string` (which it certainly should be) this part of his code is fine.

Comment: _"You're comparing pointers otherwise"_ - you can't _possibly_ know this based on the little amount of code posted. `s` could very well be `std::string` making the comparison completely valid.

Comment: Could be. But nothing in the question hints at that. My guess is as good as yours here.

Comment: @AkshayRao The fact that it works if the word is surrounded by whitespace indicates that `s` is a `std::string` (or equivalent).